# Cordova GCM plugin error

Tags: android, push-notification, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Im using a cordova plugin found here: https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova to include push notifications into my phonegab android app. The plugin works with the android project provided but I get errors when I try to import the packages to my project.

I followed all the instructions on the readme but I am getting an error at:

```
public GCMIntentService() {
super("GCMIntentService");
```

}

It says that the The constructor GCMBaseIntentService(String) is undefined.

Im a noob at native android, hence im using phonegab (lol). So does any one know why this is happening?

Im working in eclipse btw

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the step one define [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app).

> Step 1: Copy the gcm.jar file into your application classpath
>
> To write your Android application, first copy the gcm.jar file from
>   the SDK's gcm-client/dist directory to your application classpath.

and also [this step](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#libs) to install gcm libs:

> Install the Helper Libraries
>
> To perform the steps described in the
>   following sections, you must first install the helper libraries
>   (reference: client and server). From the SDK Manager, install Extras >
>   Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library. This creates a gcm
>   directory under YOUR_SDK_ROOT/extras/google/ containing these
>   subdirectories: gcm-client, gcm-server, samples/gcm-demo-client,
>   samples/gcm-demo-server, and samples/gcm-demo-appengine.
>
> Note: If you don't see Extras > Google Cloud Messaging for Android
>   Library in the SDK Manager, make sure you are running version 20 or
>   higher. Be sure to restart the SDK Manager after updating it.

EDIT1:

if you are running this n a emulator then you need to follow the following instruction given in the GCM-Cordova [lib readme.md](https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova)

> **Notes and Gotchas**
>
> If you run this demo using the emulator you will not
>   receive notifications from GCM. You need to run it on an actual device
>   to receive messages or install the proper libraries on your emulator
>   (You can follow this guide under the section titled "Installing helper
>   libraries and setting up the Emulator")
>
> If everything seems right and you are not receiving a registration id
>   response back from Google, try uninstalling and reinstalling your app.
>   That has worked for some devs out there.

Comment: Hey, I am using a cordova plugin (i include that pakage in my source directly ) so I dont really need to add that jar in.

Comment: eclipse need the jar for compilation... try with adding the jar file and let me know if there is still some issue...

Comment: hey sorry about the delay.. nd ye I added the jar file and i added the jar to the build path.. :(.. not working

Comment: can you show some code... since both the constructor in the `GCMBaseIntentService` are protected they can only be called from the sub class of `GCMBaseIntentService`...